# Using an updating function, add an item to an array but it keeps updating whilst in there

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have been trying to fix this for about 2 hours now. I have tried many different methods but I can't get it to work.

I am making a snake game in JS (I'm learning it) and I am trying to add the positions of the snake to an array.

```
this.update = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++) {
    this.tail[i + 1] = this.tail[i];
  }

  this.tail[0] = createVector(this.position.x, this.position.y);

  this.position.x += this.direction.x * 10;
  this.position.y += this.direction.y * 10;

  this.position.x = constrain(this.position.x, 0, width - 10);
  this.position.y = constrain(this.position.y, 0, height - 10);
}
```

Once I add an item to the array, it continues to update the previous one. This is really annoying.

Imgur is down so here is a an image that is debug info. https://this.is-a-professional-domain.com/8c2801.png

I am using the p5 JS library which is why I am using "createVector", however the issue still happens when I don't use that method.

Comment: `this.tail[i + 1] = this.tail[i];` so lets do an example - you are updating `this.tail[1] = this.tail[0];`. Then the next step, you are doing `this.tail[2] = this.tail[1];`, but `this.tail[1]` was already set to `this.tail[0]` in the previous step. So you are setting everything to `this.tail[0]`. Is that what you intend to do? I'd assume you want to move all one step ahead, not overwrite everything the way you do.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I didn't think about it like that. I'm trying to move everything one step forward so I can set the first item of the array to the new value.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Note that this should not be your full program, but should be a **minimal** example that we can copy-paste to see the problem on our own machines.

Comment: Managed to solve this thanks to @ASDFGerte. Thanks.